# Bool Logic + while bool and object:

Tags: python, while-loop

```
a = True
obj = {some object}

while a and obj:
    doSomething()
    certain if statements:
    ^ some of these will turn a False or obj to None
```

^Will this keep running while a = True and obj exists?

What if both are false at the same time - will False and None -> evaluate to True so it keeps running or will it exit while loop

Comment: In python `None` is synonymous with `False`. Looking at a truth table will also help with figuring out the answer.

Comment: @sean that's incorrect. `bool(None)`, `bool(False)` and `bool(0)` are all false, but `None is not False` is true.

Comment: I didn't know that either, but does it still run even if     None is not False

Comment: @Kos I believe sean was talking from the perspective of truthiness. `None` and `False` have different identities, but `None` will always evaluate to `False`.

Comment: Good Python clarifications here. Good job everyone!

Comment: @Lattyware I can't see how the term "synonymous" could relate to truthiness, not identity. `None` is an object of type `NoneType` and it doesn't magically evaluate to anything else than `None`.

Comment: @Kos It was a poor wording choice, sure, but the whole question is about truthiness, so you can see what he meant. And `None` does evaluate to `False` if you run it through `bool()` (which is the effective behaviour of `if`, `while` statements, etc...).

Comment: @Lattyware Yes, so `None` evaluates to `None` and `bool(None)` evaluates to `False`. I know English isn't a programming language but let's not obfuscate things for no good reason, shall we? ;-)

Comment: @Kos When people use the term *evaluate* in Python they usually mean truthiness (`bool(x)`) because otherwise everything evaluates to itself, which is kind of obvious. When talking about identity, *is* tends to be the word of choice (which nicely matches with Python).

Comment: @Lattyware the term *to evaluate* means *to determine the value of an expression*. You're suggesting that it should mean something else for id-expressions. This looks like an unnatural special case. Why complicate? The value of an expression and the truthiness (= truth value of an expression = `bool(expression)` are distinct concepts.

Comment: And I'm against using the term "synonymous" carelessly because it implies "you can replace A with B without changing the behaviour of your program". Let's just say that both are falsy, or both have the same truth value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will run while 'a' stays true and the obj exists

If both go False it will to evaluate to False

if just one goes to False it will evaluate to False

Try writing:

> (False and None)

in your python interpreter it will evaluate to False

Comment: You are presuming the object doesn't implement `__bool__` (or `__nonzero__` in 2.x).

Comment: Ok - thanks - for the help. The object doesn't have a __bool__method so I assume it uses Python's pre-existing one.

Answer (score 3):

> What if both are false at the same time - will False and None -> evaluate to True so it keeps running or will it exit while loop

As soon as *at least* one of the `and` operands evaluates to `False`, the loop will stop. Thus, if *both* evaluate to `False`, the loop with also stop.

It is important to note that `False` and `None` are not the only things that evaluate to `False`. See the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) for details.